# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am getting the following error:

```
"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `DeweyEdition`
BLOB NOT NULL, , `DeweyNumber` BLOB NOT NULL)' at line 1
<br />Error No: 1064<br />ALTER TABLE tt_hj_import ADD COLUMN
(`CountryOfPub` BLOB NOT NULL, , `DeweyEdition` BLOB NOT NULL, ,
`DeweyNumber` BLOB NOT NULL) in /var/www/system/database/mysql.php on line 50"
```

My code:

```
public function alterImportTable($new_fields) {
    if (!empty($new_fields)) {
        $sql = "ALTER TABLE " . DB_PREFIX . "hj_import ADD COLUMN ";
        $fields_sql = array();
        foreach ($new_fields as $field) {
            $fields_sql[] = '`' . $field . "` BLOB NOT NULL, ";
        }
        $sql .= '(' . implode(', ', $fields_sql) . ')';
        $sql = str_replace(', )', ')', $sql);
        $this->db->query($sql);
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: To ease helping you can you paste the SQL before the ``->query`` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an extra space in the query, try removing `,` after `NULL,` like this:

```
$fields_sql[] = '`' . $field . "` BLOB NOT NULL ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one `ADD COLUMN` per column.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my program, i just change the query version

```
    mysql_query($sql,$con)
```

**TO**

```
    mysqli_query($sql, $con)
```